# Flutter iOS Back Swipe does not call onWillPop

Tags: flutter, dart

I covered my `Scaffold` with a `WillPopScope`, but the `onWillPop` callback is not called when swiping to go back on iOS.
What could be the reason for this?

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      print("onWillPop"); // is not printed to the console
      if (Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress)
        return false;
      else
        return true;
    },
    child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("App Title"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...widgets...
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203#issuecomment-540663717), to make your **WillPopScope** work, you should override **hasScopedWillPopCallback** getter in **MaterialPageRoute** like this:

```
class CustomMaterialPageRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
  @protected
  bool get hasScopedWillPopCallback {
    return false;
  }
  CustomMaterialPageRoute({
    @required WidgetBuilder builder,
    RouteSettings settings,
    bool maintainState = true,
    bool fullscreenDialog = false,
  }) : super(
          builder: builder,
          settings: settings,
          maintainState: maintainState,
          fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog,
        );
}
```

And then replace **MaterialPageRoute** on **CustomMaterialPageRoute** in your **Router**. It definitely make **WillPopScope** work for both IOS and Android platforms for sure.

Comment: can you please post an example of how to replace the `MaterialPageRoute`? I'm using `AutoRouter` could't figure it out yet

Comment: Greetings, @tmaihoff. As far as I know, the auto route package generates routes right? If so, add this custom class somewhere in your code and replace all auto-generated `MaterialPageRoute` with this `CustomMaterialPageRoute ` manually by calling this `CustomMaterialPageRoute ` class. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason: WillPopScope does not work because the widget with the above build method is not a top widget (the widget called by main). I hope it helps others.

Comment: need more details

Answer (score 1):

Put this as your top-level widget, possibly inside the build function:

```
   bool canNavigateBack = true;//This should come from a Stream/bloc/etc.

return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            if (canNavigateBack) {
              //Navigate back actions
            } else {
              //Show exit dialog, etc.
            }
          }
          return Future.value(false);
        },
        child: Platform.isIOS
            ? GestureDetector(
                onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                  if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 50) {
                    if (canNavigateBack) {
                      //Navigate back actions
                    } else {
                      //Show exit dialog, etc.
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: _anotherWidget())
            : _anotherWidget(),
      );
```

Comment: Please explain what this code do.

Comment: It separates the logic for the back navigation for iOs and Android platforms, so the back swipe gesture remains available. In the if clause you handle the case, when the user can simply navigate back, e.g. you simply put a `Navigator.of(context).pop()`. In the else clause you intercept the back navigation and can show a dialog for example.

Answer (score 0):

A widget like this works.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class CustomWillPopScope extends StatelessWidget {

  const CustomWillPopScope({required this.child, this.onWillPop = false, Key? key, required this.action}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final bool onWillPop;
  final VoidCallback action;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isIOS ?
    GestureDetector(
        onPanEnd: (details) {
          if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0 || details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 0) {
            if(onWillPop){
              action();
            }
          }
        },
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: ()async{
            return false;
          },
          child: child,
        )
    )
        : WillPopScope(child: child, onWillPop: () async {
      action();
      return onWillPop;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: unable to scroll up and down with this

Answer (score -1):

this is a problem and discussed a lot in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203) but there is a way to fix it and it is to use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_will_pop_scope)

```
return ConditionalWillPopScope(
child: _MyScreenContent(),
onWillPop: _onWillPop,
shouldAddCallbacks: _hasChanges,
 );
```